# Jersey Atmosphere Broadcast not being delivered

Tags: java, websocket, jersey, tomcat7, atmosphere

I am new to Atmosphere so I must be missing something simple. I made a sample and can get the @Broadcast to work but not BroadcasterFactory to work. I can trace the onMessage to be hit (via a listener) but I dont see onBroadcast happening unless the @Broadcast is specified. Also, unless I specify the @Broadcast, I dont see the message delivered to the client. My WebSocket code is very basic:

```
@Path("/chat")
@AtmosphereService(
        interceptors = {AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class, 
                        TrackMessageSizeInterceptor.class/*,
                        BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor.class*/}//,
        )
public class HelloWorldWS {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SuspendResponse<String> connect(@Context AtmosphereResource res) 
    {
        // eventually this will be done via subscription in the post area
        BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().get().addAtmosphereResource(res);

        return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
                //.broadcaster(BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().get())
                .outputComments(true)
                .addListener(new ResourceListener())
                .build();
    }

    //@Broadcast(writeEntity = false)
    @POST
    public void broadcast(String message) {
        final String msg = String.format("{'author':'fdsa','message':'%s'}", "Override proof");
        // Send to all
        BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().get().broadcast(msg);
        // No Really, send to all
        Collection<Broadcaster> broadcasters = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookupAll();
        for (Broadcaster b : broadcasters)
        {
            System.out.println("Broadcaster: " + b.toString() + "; Count: " + b.getAtmosphereResources().size());
            for (AtmosphereResource r : b.getAtmosphereResources())
            {
                System.out.println("Notifying Resource: " + r.toString());
                r.write(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I enable the @Broadcast/BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor then the message is relayed to the client (my code in the "broadcast" function does nothing then). When I comment out the @Broadcast/BroadcastOnPostAtmosphereInterceptor then I would expect my Broadcast code to deliver the message.

With @Broadcast I show the following ResourceListener callbacks: onPreSuspend, onSuspend, onConnect, onMessage, onBroadcast (client gets it)

When @Broadcast is commented out I show the following ResourceListener callbacks: onPreSuspend, onSuspend, onConnect, onMessage (client never gets message)

What am I doing wrong?

I am using atmosphere 2.1.2 with Jersey 1.17

Answer (score -1):

get rid of AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor is you use the SuspendResponse API as it may conflict.

Comment: This does not appear to be a link to an answer, mustaccio, but a link to an external forum. Which is, of course, even worse for SO.